# View Layers Panel

Tags: viewlayers

I have a relatively simple Blend for testing: a couple Suzanne's and some text. I want to be able to render either just the normal image, or the depth map image.

In the *Compositor*, I've created two Render Groups: 1 to render the depth map ("Depth Map View Layer Render"), 1 to render the normal image (with background image) ("Normal View Layer Render").

**What The Manual Says about the View Layer Panel:** "Use for Rendering - The ***active view layer*** will be used during rendering."
https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/render/layers/layers.html

**What Actually Happens:** Whichever *View Layer Group* I have selected in the Compositor gets rendered (OR if NEITHER group is currently selected, then the last selected group), regardless of which *View Layer* is active in the *View Layer Panel*.

**Note:** selecting the ***Render Single Layer*** option in the *View Layer Properties* panel **has no effect** on which group gets rendered.

What am I missing? Yes, I can accomplish what I want, but is this "*normal*" behavior? [I've never tried this in previous versions).

**Blender Versions:** 2.81 and 2.82a

[image]

Comment: Hi. Please make the title of the question specific to what you are asking and not just the general topic. Thanks.

Comment: Short answer: You are using 2 *Viewer* and 2 *Composite* nodes. The one which is currently active (red vs grey) will be rendered. Only put down 1 of them and you are good to go.